# I need a lightbox plugin that will apply to gallery

Tags: plugins, lightbox

I have a gallery on my page, in this type of syntax:

```
[gallery ids="1588,1584,1582,1583,1581"]
```

I would like each image to open up in a lightbox.  I've tried the Simple Lightbox plugin, which looks very good, but it doesn't take effect on my site.  It requires the_content() to be run on my page template, but I looked at page.php, and I don't see that function being called.  I'm using the Nevia theme.

I read SLB's directions, and I don't think I missed any steps.  So I wonder if there is another similar plugin that I can use.  After searching on Google, I found a lot of things that are somewhat like what I need, but I don't have time to try each one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: Responsive Lightbox by dFactory.  It doesn't require the function the_content(), or make any mention of any required functions.